# windows phone 8 custom message box

Tags: windows-phone-8, messagebox, customdialog

I want to implement a dialog(or alert dialog) like extending Dialog component in Android.

In phone 8 message box only allows showing title and message. I would like to add new views like button, images etc to my dialog. How can i achive this, or is it possible?

thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) contains an example of a custom message box, which already allows some more (although still limited, imo) freedom. If that one doesn't fullfil your requirements, you can just peek at the source to get an idea as how to go about rolling your own message box.

If memory serves, it uses a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) internally, to display a modal screen.

Comment: Can you place an image as the Content of CustomMessageBox? I am having trouble setting my image as the Content, nothing shows up.